# How can I check that onKeyPress has NOT fired after onKeyDown?

Tags: javascript, html

Some keys fire both onKeyDown and onKeyPress events, such as `A` and some keys only fire onKeyDown, such as `SHIFT`. How can I check that onKeyPress *hasn't* been fired for a particular key? I need to detect it as soon as the key is depressed, so I can't use onKeyUp because of the delay.

Comment: a solution from the top of my head, use a var to track an onkeyPress event is fired, then use setTimeout with 0 delay to enqueue a new event to the event table that will execute after all events are done (at that point you can check if both are fired or just one)

Answer (score 1):

You can only use onKeyUp in this case, because onKeyPress is fired after onKeyDown and before onKeyUp. You could store whether onKeyPress has been fired for a key like this:

```js
var keyPressedFired = false;

document.addEventListener("keypress", function(e) {
    keyPressedFired = true;
});

document.addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {
    if (!keyPressedFired) {
        alert('KeyPress not fired this key');
    }

    keyPressedFired = false;
});
```

*Run the snippet, click on the white part below it and press SHIFT*

Comment: Hold down `A` then hold down `SHIFT`. Release `SHIFT` then release `A`. A message pops up saying `KeyPress not fired this key` which is incorrect.